# Can Yubikey complement a TPM chip?

Tags: tpm, yubikey

Does the functionality of an external hardware key overlaps 100% with the one provided by an embedded security chip on a laptop? Or can they complement each other?

Although I assume an external key is safer and more practical (device portability) I wonder if they can complement a TPM chip

Comment: Not sure if they are talking about the same, but yubikey guys have [a doc](https://www.yubico.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/YubiKey-Integration-for-Full-Disk-Encryption-with-Pre-Boot-Authentication-v1.2.pdf) about full disk encryption and pre-boot-authentication. I wonder if they TPM == PBA in that 
 doc.

Comment: Closest thing I have seen is this: [LUKS + Yubikey + AEM](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/qubes-users/I5clx1E-S9M/discussion) which is an implementation of the full disk encryption paper of the yubikey guys. The AEM is descrived [here](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/anti-evil-maid/)

Comment: In windows there are guides on [TPM + bitlocker + yubikey](https://legallygeeky.net/?p=511)